# How to use routes in TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm getting to know **TypeORM**, I created the project from its [Quick Start](https://typeorm.io/#/undefined/quick-start) documentation, including the same folder hierarchy, I followed all the steps and I was created a project that worked correctly. But the standard project created has only 1 route which is User with its controller and its entity, having in its main file the following declaration:

### index.ts

```
import {Routes} from "./routes";

createConnection().then(async connection => {

  // create express app
  const app = express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  // register express routes from defined application routes
  Routes.forEach(route => {
    (app as any)[route.method](route.route, (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) => {
        const result = (new (route.controller as any))[route.action](req, res, next);
        if (result instanceof Promise) {
            result.then(result => result !== null && result !== undefined ? res.send(result) : undefined);

        } else if (result !== null && result !== undefined) {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
...
```

### user.ts - (Entity)

```
import {UserController} from "../controller/UserController";

export const Users = [{
  method: "get",
  route: "/users",
  controller: UserController,
  action: "all"
}, {
  method: "get",
  route: "/users/:id",
  controller: UserController,
  action: "one"
}, {    
  method: "post",
  route: "/users",
  controller: UserController,
  action: "save"
}, {
  method: "delete",
  route: "/users/:id",
  controller: UserController,
  action: "remove"
}];
```

### UserController.ts

```
import {getRepository} from "typeorm";
import {NextFunction, Request, Response} from "express";
import {Users} from "../entity/User";

export class UserController {

  private userRepository = getRepository(Users);

  async all(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.find()
  }

  async one(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.findOne(request.params.id);
  }

  async save(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.save(request.body);
  }

  async remove(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let userToRemove = await this.userRepository.findOne(request.params.id);
    await this.userRepository.remove(userToRemove);
  }

}
```

My doubts would be as follows:

- Is there a way to go with this structure with more than one route or is this pattern just for 1 route?
- If there is a possibility to continue with this structure, how would you declare another route for example?

Comment: The structure is not that bad however I suggest you to try [NestJS](https://nestjs.com) | [Controllers](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers). You can use typeORM and is typescript based (and much more).

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when there's already one and made better :)